# How to Compute this Lie Bracket in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Here's the problem: Consider the following vector fields on $\mathbb {H}^1$($3$-dimensional Heisenberg Group) $$X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}y\frac{\partial }{\partial t}
,\qquad Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-\frac{1}{2}x\frac{\partial }{\partial t}$$and $$T=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$
I have already proven that these three vectors are left-invariant vector fields
How do I compute the Lie brackets $[X,Y]$? I know that $$[X,Y]=XY-YX$$ and I know that  $[X,Y]$=$-T$
but it gives me $0$ instead of $-T$. Is the order of the partial derivatives wrong? Am I applying the formula correctly? Any help is appreciated
Here is my attempt
https://photos.app.goo.gl/DQXeiu6BrUnmqKqH8
Here are pictures of the other passages
https://photos.app.goo.gl/x5zzgj7fk4gs3XYE8
I have solved my problem thank you, solution follows

Comment: Don't use picture inclusion. Instead turn to Latex : here is an example for the roots of a quadratic equation `$ax^2+bx+c=0$` : `$x_1,x_2=\frac{1}{2a}(-b \pm \sqrt{\Delta})$`, for partial derivatives `$\partial f/\partial x$`, etc.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: I am actually extremely bad at latex(if i used it then its literally not understandable),like the worst,i been trying to solve this problem for 8 hours and I am stumped

Comment: Can we see the passages you've done to get to $0$? Because I used the definition and got the right result, so the error is in the calculations

Comment: @Alessandro Sure,here my attempt https://photos.app.goo.gl/DQXeiu6BrUnmqKqH8,get zero,for the other commutators like (X,T) and (X,X) ... I get zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see your mistake: You make vector fields commute, which of course makes the Lie brackets $=0$. For example (I'm referring to the pictures posted on the question), on the first page you write $$\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\partial_t\right)\partial_x=\partial _x\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\partial _t\right)=\cdots$$ (where I used $\partial_u$ instead of $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$) this is wrong, because look at how the two compositions act: In $$\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\partial_t\right)\partial_x$$you first differentiate by $x$, then you differentiate by $t$ and finally multiply the result by $-\frac{1}{2}x$. On the other hand, with $$\partial _x\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\partial _t\right)$$you differentiate by $t$, then multiply by $-\frac{1}{2}x$ and finally differentiate by $x$, in particular you differentiate $-\frac{1}{2}x$ as well, when in the first composition you just multiply by it. Of course, if there was a constant instead of $-\frac{1}{2}x$, this wouldn't be an issue, since differential operators are linear over $\mathbb R$

Comment: Sorry for not saying thank you after you wrote such a wonderful and detailed explanation, I finally got (X,Y)=-T,@Alessandro,thank you very much https://photos.app.goo.gl/zR3FJ2tdk6Cvfafm8

Comment: No problem, you're welcome